# Writing several lines to batch process

Tags: java, batch-file, input, process, output

I'm trying to provide input for simple batch file, that expecting two lines of input:

```
@echo off

set /p file1="Enter: "
set /p file2="Enter: "
echo "1" > %file2%
```

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",  "/c", "test.cmd").start();

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()))) {
        bw.write("1");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("2");
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

And I'm expecting that file with name "2" will be created, but nothing happens.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't think you can use `Process` to execute a process and force its  standard input to read lines you provide.  You need `ProcessBuilder`.  Also, you may not be able to execute a batch file directly, although I'm not sure.  You may have to execute `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @ajb tried both (process builder and use cmd.exe). same result here. i've updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
                InputStream in = p.getInputStream()) {
            in.read();
            bw.write("1");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            bw.write("2");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
```

Basically, you have to read the content before writing.
Else, Java may start write even before the sub process promting for input. So your write will not consider.

And don't forgot to flush

you can debug using `waitFor` without read. it will wait forever to get the input.

Note**, File location based on the input in second line. In your case it would create in the directory from where the java got executed.

Rather you can just try actual path like.

```
bw.write("C:/projects/test.txt");
```

Would create in specified path as per your commands in cmd

UPDATE
    I thought i did explained why we need to call read first. let me try explain in detail in a way i understood.

By calling `process.getRunTime().exec` - you are creating new `process` which can run parallel. Your main process will start process immediately . So we have two process (1. Main 2. process we started) both are running in parallel. Assume the main process executes next line (writing ) before the sub process(cmd) prompting ( since both are in parallel. this can happen). what ever main process writes on sub process would be waste because sub process is not in listening mode.

That why we have call read on sub process from main process . So that the Main Process would wait until the sub process prompt for input.

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you. Could you explain, why should I read before writing?